# React Native build error: GeneratedInfoPlistDotEnv.h' file not found

Tags: ios, react-native

I am not using react-native-config here. Still during react-native run-ios I am getting below error.

:1:10: fatal error: '/Users/anurag/cmg/cmg/cmg_app/ios/build/Build/Products/GeneratedInfoPlistDotEnv.h' file not found

## include "/Users/anurag/cmg/cmg/cmg_app/ios/build/Build/Products/GeneratedInfoPlistDotEnv.h"

```
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

1 error generated.

** BUILD FAILED **

The following build commands failed:
    Preprocess build/Build/Intermediates.noindex/cmg_app.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/cmg_app.build/Preprocessed-Info.plist cmg_app/Info.plist
(1 failure)

Thanks in Advance